# Can I use hyperlinks as a form submit which posts $_GET values instead of making an hyperlink which has $_GET values?

Tags: html, url, hyperlink, get, form-submit

I am using many get values in one page and making up a hyperlink with adding ?var=value&... each time is time cosuming. I would like to use hyperlinks as a submit button in a form and html would attach the variables to the url right away.

Update: I used this method and it worked fine now.

```
<a href="index.php?
<? foreach($_GET as $gk=>$gv)
{
echo $gk."=".$gv."&";
} 
?>
pager=
<? echo $i; ?>">
<? echo $i; ?>
</a>
```

Update 2:
Making url's is too much of a work, now I decided to use hidden fields in current forms and getting get values as default for the hiddent values. For preserving the get values, I won't be making a link. I'll post same get values from a get form. it works just fine. and I like using standard forms because the standard things work best.

Comment: You can also use "normal" submit buttons and style them via css to look "like" links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make a function in php that writes all the $_GET variables for you:

```
function WriteGetForHyperlink ( $array ) {
    $output = "?";
    foreach ( $array as $key=>$value ) {
        $output .= $key.'='.$value.'&';
    }
    return $output;
}
```

Then your HTML link could be:

```
<a href='wherever.html<?= WriteGetForHyperlink( $_GET ) ?>'>Link</a>
```

Doing this will allow you to add more get variables to the end of the link, or you could pass custom arrays (so instead of all the $_GET, maybe only two or three parts of it), and you don't need to use javascript or have a lot of HTML on a page that is unnecessary.

**OR**

If you were set on using a form, you could do create a form with a bunch of hidden elements:

```
<form method='GET' action='wherever.html'>
 <input type='hidden' name='var1' value='1' />
 <input type='hidden' name='var1' value='1' />
 <input type='submit' class='submit-link' value='Link' />
</form>
```

Here is some CSS:

```
input.submit-link {
    border: none;
    background: Transparent;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #00f
}
input.submit-link:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<a href="javascript:document.formname.submit();">Submit</a>
```

it will submit the form with attribute name="formname". if the attribute method="get" then all your submitted data will be send to your attribute action="url.php" with the parameters.

Comment: Although this works with no problems, I often don't like relying on Javascript to submit a link that doesn't need to use Javascript (just to make things easier for me as a developer to read/create).

Answer (score 1):

you've got two options to achieve that: 
the 1st is to use the standard

```
<input type="submit" />
```

button, that you can lately style via css to make it look like a link.
or, if you are forced to use a link to accomplish this task, you can point to a javascript solution. from the easy way like

```
<a href="javascript:document.getElementById('myFormId').submit()" />
```

to a more elaborate one, that involves a framework like mootools or jquery